# digital signature

Tags: digital-signature

All,

I need to digitally sign a zip file. I am not sure how to do that. What does the digital signature do for me? And just as importantly, how do i verify the digital signature?

Comment: What OS are you using, and do you need to be compatible with any particular programs?

Comment: Windows and Mac, no specific need but lets say 7zip for now

Comment: Should the digital signature be included in the zip file or is an detached signature (separate file) acceptable? Additionally who/which program will verify the signature?

Comment: @Robert, What difference does this make? ie detached Vs attached. I am trying to understand, here. Thanks

Comment: It makes a difference if you want to use an existing application for verifying the signature. For detached signatures a common approach would be to use GnuPG (Gnu variant of Pretty Good Privacy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a great reading on JAR signing (http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/85application/jar/sign.html) and having in mind that JAR is a ZIP with a MANIFEST, I'd say you go with JAR signing and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of APPNOTE (this is where PKWare publishes ZIP format specification) describe digital signature of ZIP archives. The problem is that they don't let one implement signing functionality and reserve it for their own use in their SecureZip software. From legal point of view you are allowed only to perform validation of ZIP archive signatures.

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-zip.php) component library includes ZIP processing components, which include, among many other functions, validation of ZIP archive signatures. We attempted to acquire a license from PKWare to perform signing as well, but they didn't even discuss such option internally, so they were not able to give us a definite answer.