# How to sign a zip file on a machine where a certificate is installed of which I do not know the path?

Tags: sign, signing, signtool

My employer has given me access to a VM where a certificate is installed. I tried sign installers (of the software I create) using the [signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) and I succeeded. However, I also need to sign zip files. I have not succeeded so far. Here is the command-line statement:

```
signtool.exe sign /i "SOMEISSUERNAME" /fd SHA256 /a /v /t http://timestamp.digicert.com something.zip
```

This fails. Here is the error message:

> SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not
> recognized.

I have searched online for solutions. The solutions I found online refer to the "the path to your certificate" ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126302/1987258)). But I do not have that path. What I know is what is written in an email that I need to refer to the right issuername, which I did. It is working for installers but not for zip files.

Can I sign my zip file in such way as well? Or do I really need the path to my certificate?

Answer (score 4):

The error message from signtool is telling you that the .zip format is not recognized.

Signtool is only able to sign PE (portable executable) filetypes and a few others, such as applications (.EXE, .cpl, .scr, .sys, etc), .DLL, .OCX, drivers, installers (.MSI, .APPX), .CAB, and .CAT files.
ZIP files with a .zip extension are not supported for signing.

One option is to convert the .zip to a self-extracting(SFX) .EXE archive or bundle the contents into an installer that can be signed.

Answer (score 1):

A .zip file isn't an app, and it can't be signed, so it is unable to be signed by Signtool.

Answer (score 0):

Zip does not have a signature standard. As @Superbob mentioned, you can create a self-extracting executable file for signing.

Or create your own program to sign and verify the signature and pack the zip file with your program. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16652058)

Another solution is to use a seperate `Catalog` file, and shipping the catalog file with your zip file. [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126302)

Comment: The last option looks like a real solution. However, it requires me to know the "the path to your certificate", which I, as explained, do not have (the certificate is installed by my employer and the file itself is not accessible for me). Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @Daan you mean you cannot access the Certificate Manager (certmgr.msc) to get a `Cert:\` URN?